# Martian source and sysctl

Tags: redhat, sysctl

Okay, so I have one machine with this config:

```ini
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 0
```

And, after a `sysctl -p`, it stopped flooding the `/var/log/messages` (as it should).

But I have this other machine, with an `sdiff sysctl`, identical to the first machine, that keeps flooding the `/var/log/messages` with the martian source warnings.

I had to do this

```ini
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.log_martians = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.log_martians = 0
```

in order to stop the messages from appearing.

And I can't really understand why it needed the additional specific `.ethx` lines.

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Does both machines have two (2) network interfaces like `eth0` and `eth1`? Or only the second one? Do you have more information regarding both (system, setup, versions, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this earlier. After a clean reboot, the messages disappeared.